# Vue.js Component doesn't show data from method of component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am new to Vue.JS (2) and I am trying to learn components now. I try to use a component in another component with data from a data method (I know you can't use the property Data in a component). My code now:

HTML

```
<div id="root">

    <h1>Tasks</h1>

    <list></list>

</div>
```

JS

```
Vue.component('list', {

    template: '<task v-for="task in tasks">{{ task.task }}</task>',

    data: function()  {

        return {

            tasks: [

                {task: 'Go to the store', completed: false},
                {task: 'Go to the shop', completed: true},
                {task: 'Go to the mall', completed: true}
            ]

        };
    }

});


Vue.component('task', {

    template: '<li><slot></slot></li>'

});


new Vue({

    el: '#root'

});
```

this will return a white screen. If I remove the data, and just use a string in the task template it shows the string, so the component "task" is working in the component "list".

```
Vue.component('list', {

    template: '<task>Test</task>',


});


Vue.component('task', {

    template: '<li><slot></slot></li>'

});


new Vue({

    el: '#root'

});
```

So it seems like there is something wrong with displaying the data to the view with the method/data. I've tried many things but I just can't get it right.

Any help would be great, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Basics),

> components must contain exactly one root node.

Putting a `v-for` on the top-level element makes it repeated. If you wrap that element in a `div`, it works.

It looks like you may get around that limitation if you want to write your own `render` function.

```js
Vue.component('my-list', {
  template: '<div><task v-for="task in tasks">{{ task.task }}</task></div>',
  data() {
    return {
      tasks: [{
          task: 'Go to the store',
          completed: false
        },
        {
          task: 'Go to the shop',
          completed: true
        },
        {
          task: 'Go to the mall',
          completed: true
        }
      ]
    };
  }
});

Vue.component('task', {
  template: '<li><slot></slot></li>'
});

new Vue({
  el: '#root'
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.5/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <h1>Tasks</h1>
  <my-list></my-list>
</div>
```

Comment: If you install Vue Devtools, you will see this error pop up in your dev console when the page tries to render.

Comment: I knew about this.. have looked everywhere for the mistake in the code but didn't notice I forgot to include that. Must be tired :) Thanks